# Flutter transparency issues in google chrome

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome, transparency

Yesterday I was working on my Flutter app and everything was fine. This morning I ran the build and I noticed that in google chrome half transparant images are no longer transparent.

So I have this image as example

[image]

Where the white should be transparent

This is some example code

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyPage(),
  ));
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset('images/test/circle_gradient.png'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Where this is the actual image

[image]

This only happens on google chrome and not on Safari. I am working on a macbook pro m1. And here is my flutter version.

```
Fluter version: 
Flutter 3.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fb57da5f94 (5 weeks ago) • 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
Engine • revision caaafc5604
Tools • Dart 2.17.1 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

Comment: It works fine for me, though I run Flutter 3.0.2, Tools • Dart 2.17.3 • DevTools 2.12.2

Comment: Nevermind, I upgraded Chrome and now it doesn't anymore. It worked fine in Chrome 102. Stopped working in Chrome 103. So maybe a Chrome bug

Comment: I see someone else noticed it here: https://issuemode.com/issues/flutter/flutter/95527066